# Configuring ssh access via jump box and pbrun

Tags: ssh

In an RHEL6 environment with Powerbroker and no direct access to hosts, I can hop to them via jump box/gateway:

This explicit command works, without configuration, however it's verbose:

```
dk@local $ ssh -t dk@gateway 'pbrun -u sysuser -h remote bash'
dk@gateway's password:
sysuser@remote's password:

sysuser@remote $
```

I am looking for a way/configuration to simplify the above command to something like `ssh remote`.
As shown above, the end result should be being logged in as sysuser (not dk). Note the authentication via Powerbroker (pbrun command).

Is it possible to achieve this simply via  `~/.ssh/config`? If so, do you spot any obvious fixes for the commands/config that I've tried?

---

**Limitations**:

1. I cannot establish trust between servers using Public Key Authentication (PKA), because it's forbidden by the security policy. All authentication must be done via Powerbroker (see pbrun command above)
2. Authentication from gateway to the remote is enforced via Powerbroker (see the `pbrun` command).

---

**What I've tried:**

```
dk@local $ cat .ssh/config
Host behindProxy
     HostName remote
     ProxyCommand ssh -t dk@gateway 'pbrun -u sysuser -h %h bash'

dk@local $ ssh behindProxy
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
dk@gateway's password:
pbrun8.5.1-01[4377]: 3346: TTY is no longer available
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
dk@local $
```

```
dk@local $ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host behindProxy
     HostName remote
     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p dk@gateway 'pbrun -u sysuser -h %h bash'
dk@local $ ssh behindProxy
dk@gateway's password:
dk@remote's password:
dk@remote $               # undesired, as the goal is to end up logged in as sysuser (see the pbrun command)
```

```
dk@local $ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host behindProxy
     ProxyJump gateway
     ProxyCommand pbrun -u sysuser -h remote bash

dk@local $ ssh behindProxy
dk@gateway's password:
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two configurations that I found working are:

```
dk@local $ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host behindProxy
     HostName gateway
     LocalCommand pbrun -u sysuser -h remote bash
     PermitLocalCommand yes

dk@local $ ssh behindProxy
dk@gateway's password:
sysuser@remote's password:

sysuser@remote $
```

The connection, however, does not really come from the gateway:

```
sysuser@remote $ last -1 -w
dk pts/18       local.domain.com Sun Nov  8 22:03   still logged in
```

---

Alternatively:

```
dk@local $ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host behindProxy2
     HostName gateway
     RemoteCommand pbrun -u sysuser -h remote bash

dk@local $ ssh -t behindProxy2
dk@gateway's password:
sysuser@remote's password:

sysuser@remote $
```

Proof that connection truly comes via the gateway:

```
sysuser@remote $ last -1 -w
dk pts/18       gateway.domain.com Sun Nov  8 22:06 still logged in
```

Note the `-t` option is necessary here, otherwise error ensues:

```
dk@local $ ssh behindProxy2
dk@gateway's password:
sysuser@remote's password: pbrun8.5.1-01[20295]: 3346: TTY is no longer available
```

It's possible to avoid having to supply `-t`, by specifying `RequestTTY force`:

```
dk@local $ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host behindProxy2
     HostName gateway
     RequestTTY force
     RemoteCommand pbrun -u sysuser -h remote bash

dk@local $ ssh behindProxy2
dk@gateway's password:
sysuser@remote's password:

sysuser@remote $
```

Comment: i've just seen your answer LocalCommand is executed on your local machiine you should use  RemoteCommand instead. that means that you have used a direct access from local to remote without passing through the gateway

Comment: @RedaSalih, updated the answer. it doesn't seem it was the direct access in the case of the `LocalCommand` - note the order of the two authentication prompts. I suspect `LocalCommand` means in the context of the `HostName` - in this case "gateway", not "local" machine

Comment: Could you check auth audit logs on the remote to check the source ip your are login from ?

Comment: @RedaSalih good point, edited.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way can be using ssh JumpHosts, you can use ssh keys to avoid typing the password two times :

```
ssh -J <username>@<gateway_host>:<port> <username>@<remote_host>:<port>
```

Since your last edit :

First you cannot use both ProxyJump and ProxyCommand at the same time since ProxyJump is a shorthand to ProxyCommand with ssh and some parameters.

A better way is to ssh direclty on the ProxyCommand directive :

```
Host behindProxy 
    HostName gateway 
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p sysuser@remote 'bash'
```

Another way can be using **RemoteCommand** with using **pbrun** as suggested in the comment section.

Comment: note that the authentication between gateway and remote must be done via `pbrun` - it's a security policy. also no sudo access or PKA authentication allowed. i've edited my question with the failed attempt using `ProxyJump`

Comment: i have made an edit then.

Comment: noted regarding `ProxyJump` vs `ProxyCommand`. your configuration still fails, because it does not log in via `pbrun` (see limitation #2)